# Validation error while saving record

Tags: validation-rule

I have a custom object and 2 users from same profile are seeing different behaviours.

- Although the CRED access on the profile is CRE, the 1st user is able to edit it while the 2nd one cant.
- There are no validation rules or Triggers on the object.
- No Permission set is assigned to both users.

The 2nd user sees the following validation error.

I am unable to create debug logs as the profile doesn't have access to 'SetUp' (when I create a Permission Set to grant access to 'SetUp', it opens up the visiblity to all data and hence the user doesnt face the issue anymore).

Please help me if you have encountered similar issues.
​​​​​​​[image]

Comment: you (as admin) can create debug logs for any running user, their profiles don't need to be changed. You should also use [edit] and define your OWD

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include details about the org-wide sharing rules for the object.

Comment: Thaks David and croredy. 1. Although I am creating debug logs and logging in as the User#2, the debug logs are not getting created (while it's getting created when I as an Admin do the same updates). The OWD for the object is Public RW. Please let me know if you need any further information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. It was straight under my eyes and I missed the basics. The OWD is 'Public RO'-- Changed it to "Public RW"